# Video tag with input from Camera is Working in Safari on iOS but neither working in Chrome nor in any In-app Browser

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, vue.js, html5-video

The video streaming works perfectly well for Android, and Safari in iOS. The problem occurs when we try to use Chrome on iOS or an In-app Browser. I am using Vue as a Single File Component.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<video
  height="400px"
  width="300px"
  autoplay
  playsinline
/>
```

My Vue JS code is as follows:

```
data: () => ({
  video: null,
}),
mounted() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    // Prioritize Rear Camera
    video: {facingMode: 'environment'},
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    this.video = document.querySelector('video');
    this.video.srcObject = stream;
    this.video.tracks = stream.getTracks();
  });
}
```

Any help or alternative methods to solve this would be appreciated. My goal is to start a stream from the camera on the webpage and take a photo on click.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I am attempting to open the console for my mobile device. Apparently, It isn't as straightforward to get it for Chrome on iOS. If anything pops up, I'll update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the [information here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en) Chrome, Firefox, and Edge for iOS do not support the navigator.mediaDevices property due to the fact that under the hood they all use the built-in WebKit rendering engine which does not provide this capability to third parties. There is a bug [filed here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458) which includes some promising discussions about how iOS 13.4 may have *partially* resolved this.

Until Apple decides to provide this, the only option is to check `navigator.mediaDevices` for null and catch errors on the promise:

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices == null) { /* unsupported */ }
else {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({})
    .then((stream) => {})
    .catch((err) => { /* unsupported */ })
}
```

...and provide users with the appropriate feedback.